# Como fazer BETWEEN no CAKEPHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados e preciso pegar informações entre dois valores da coluna `valor` que fiquem dentro da quantidade especificada.

Por exemplo: Entre o `valorMinimo` 300 e `valorMaximo` 600

```
$imovel = $this->Imovel->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'valor' => $queries['valorMin'], 'valor' => $queries['valorMax']
    )
));
```

Comment: Nota de desempenho: `BETWEEN` é menos eficiente que fazer um `>=` e `<=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [própria documentação do CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html), sua condição ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
$imovel = $this->Imovel->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array('valor BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
            $queries['valorMin'],
            $queries['valorMax'])
        )
    )
);
```

PS: favor testar, não é meu framework principal :)

Comment: Não tem que ficar dentro do `conditions`?

Comment: @Ricardo é verdade, acabei de conferir a documentação e é isso mesmo.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in
@RodrigoRigotti

Comment: @Furlan corrigido, confere aí.